# K-means for color quantization - Code not vectorized

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing, vectorization, k-means

I'm doing this exercise by Andrew NG about using k-means to reduce the number of colors in an image. It worked correctly but I'm afraid it's a little slow because of all the for loops in the code, so I'd like to vectorize them. But there are those loops that I just can't seem to vectorize effectively. Please help me, thank you very much!

Also if possible please give some feedback on my coding style :)

Here is the [link of the exercise](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex9/ex9.html), and here is the [dataset](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/courses/MachineLearning/exercises/ex9materials/ex9Data.zip). 
The correct result is given in the link of the exercise.

And here is my code:

```
function [] = KMeans()

    Image = double(imread('bird_small.tiff'));
    [rows,cols, RGB] = size(Image);
    Points = reshape(Image,rows * cols, RGB);
    K = 16;
    Centroids = zeros(K,RGB);    
    s = RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',0);
    % Initialization :
    % Pick out K random colours and make sure they are all different
    % from each other! This prevents the situation where two of the means
    % are assigned to the exact same colour, therefore we don't have to 
    % worry about division by zero in the E-step 
    % However, if K = 16 for example, and there are only 15 colours in the
    % image, then this while loop will never exit!!! This needs to be
    % addressed in the future :( 
    % TODO : Vectorize this part!
    done = false;
    while done == false
        RowIndex = randperm(s,rows);
        ColIndex = randperm(s,cols);
        RowIndex = RowIndex(1:K);
        ColIndex = ColIndex(1:K);
        for i = 1 : K
            for j = 1 : RGB
                Centroids(i,j) = Image(RowIndex(i),ColIndex(i),j);
            end
        end
        Centroids = sort(Centroids,2);
        Centroids = unique(Centroids,'rows'); 
        if size(Centroids,1) == K
            done = true;
        end
    end;
%     imshow(imread('bird_small.tiff'))
%    
%     for i = 1 : K
%         hold on;
%         plot(RowIndex(i),ColIndex(i),'r+','MarkerSize',50)
%     end



    eps = 0.01; % Epsilon
    IterNum = 0;
    while 1
        % E-step: Estimate membership given parameters 
        % Membership: The centroid that each colour is assigned to
        % Parameters: Location of centroids
        Dist = pdist2(Points,Centroids,'euclidean');

        [~, WhichCentroid] = min(Dist,[],2);

        % M-step: Estimate parameters given membership
        % Membership: The centroid that each colour is assigned to
        % Parameters: Location of centroids
        % TODO: Vectorize this part!
        OldCentroids = Centroids;
        for i = 1 : K
            PointsInCentroid = Points((find(WhichCentroid == i))',:);
            NumOfPoints = size(PointsInCentroid,1);
            % Note that NumOfPoints is never equal to 0, as a result of
            % the initialization. Or .... ???????
            if NumOfPoints ~= 0 
                Centroids(i,:) = sum(PointsInCentroid , 1) / NumOfPoints ;
            end
        end    

        % Check for convergence: Here we use the L2 distance
        IterNum = IterNum + 1;
        Margins = sqrt(sum((Centroids - OldCentroids).^2, 2));
        if sum(Margins > eps) == 0
            break;
        end

    end
    IterNum;
    Centroids ;


    % Load the larger image
    [LargerImage,ColorMap] = imread('bird_large.tiff');
    LargerImage = double(LargerImage);
    [largeRows,largeCols,NewRGB] = size(LargerImage);  % RGB is always 3     
    % TODO: Vectorize this part!    
    largeRows
    largeCols
    NewRGB
    % Replace each of the pixel with the nearest centroid    
    NewPoints = reshape(LargerImage,largeRows * largeCols, NewRGB);
    Dist = pdist2(NewPoints,Centroids,'euclidean');
    [~,WhichCentroid] = min(Dist,[],2);
    NewPoints = Centroids(WhichCentroid,:);
    LargerImage = reshape(NewPoints,largeRows,largeCols,NewRGB);

%     for i = 1 : largeRows 
%         for j = 1 : largeCols
%             Dist = pdist2(Centroids,reshape(LargerImage(i,j,:),1,RGB),'euclidean');
%             [~,WhichCentroid] = min(Dist);    
%             LargerImage(i,j,:) = Centroids(WhichCentroid,:);            
%         end
%     end

    % Display new image
    imshow(uint8(round(LargerImage)),ColorMap)
```

UPDATE: Replaced

```
for i = 1 : K
            for j = 1 : RGB
                Centroids(i,j) = Image(RowIndex(i),ColIndex(i),j);
            end
        end
```

with

```
for i = 1 : K
            Centroids(i,:) = Image(RowIndex(i),ColIndex(i),:);
        end
```

I think this may be vectorized further by using linear indexing, but for now I should just focus on the while loop since it takes most of the time.
Also when I tried @Dev-iL's suggestion and replaced

```
for i = 1 : K
        PointsInCentroid = Points((find(WhichCentroid == i))',:);
        NumOfPoints = size(PointsInCentroid,1);
        % Note that NumOfPoints is never equal to 0, as a result of
        % the initialization. Or .... ???????
        if NumOfPoints ~= 0 
            Centroids(i,:) = sum(PointsInCentroid , 1) / NumOfPoints ;
        end
    end
```

with

```
E = sparse(1:size(WhichCentroid), WhichCentroid' , 1, Num, K, Num);
Centroids = (E * spdiags(1./sum(E,1)',0,K,K))' * Points ;
```

the results were always worse: With K = 16, the first takes 2,414s , the second takes 2,455s ; K = 32, the first takes 4,529s , the second takes 5,022s. Seems like vectorization does not help, but maybe there's something wrong with my code :( .

Comment: Consider uploading questions such as this to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) next time. Also, did you try to compare your code with known-to-work MATLAB implementations such as [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24616-kmeans-clustering)?

Comment: @Dev-iL I haven't. I have only tested this on the exercise in the link, and the result was the same with the author's, although his implementation takes a longer time than mine

Comment: I should explain myself better: what I meant is that you asked help with vectorization, and the code I linked contains a vectorized version of k-means, just like what you want. You could compare relevant parts of your implementation to the corresponding parts of the linked code to see how they can be vectorized. If you have questions about how exactly some part of the algorithm was vectorized in the linked example you can ask about it. If the linked code is still not optimized enough for your needs, you can also ask about *that*. Make sure you understand the linked code fully as a first step.

Comment: @Dev-iL Ok,  I have a question. In the line: m = X*(E*spdiags(1./sum(E,1)',0,k,k));  , the Matlab page says that :" A = spdiags(B,d,m,n) creates an m-by-n sparse matrix by taking the columns of B and placing them along the diagonals specified by d." But here 1/sum(E,1)' is just a vector ! How is it possible? Am I missing something ? :(

Comment: @Dev-iL Why isn't anyone helping me? :(

Comment: I'm assuming that people see this is  already answered, and don't bother with it anymore. Possibly because it's not the right site. Maybe they have nothing to add.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced

```
for i = 1 : K
            for j = 1 : RGB
                Centroids(i,j) = Image(RowIndex(i),ColIndex(i),j);
            end
        end
```

with

```
for i = 1 : K
            Centroids(i,:) = Image(RowIndex(i),ColIndex(i),:);
        end
```

I think this may be vectorized further by using linear indexing, but for now I should just focus on the while loop since it takes most of the time.
Also when I tried @Dev-iL's suggestion and replaced

```
for i = 1 : K
        PointsInCentroid = Points((find(WhichCentroid == i))',:);
        NumOfPoints = size(PointsInCentroid,1);
        % Note that NumOfPoints is never equal to 0, as a result of
        % the initialization. Or .... ???????
        if NumOfPoints ~= 0 
            Centroids(i,:) = sum(PointsInCentroid , 1) / NumOfPoints ;
        end
    end
```

with

```
E = sparse(1:size(WhichCentroid), WhichCentroid' , 1, Num, K, Num);
Centroids = (E * spdiags(1./sum(E,1)',0,K,K))' * Points ;
```

the results were always worse: With K = 16, the first takes 2,414s , the second takes 2,455s ; K = 32, the first took 4,529s , the second took 5,022s. Seems like vectorization did not help in this case.

However, when I replaced

```
 Dist = pdist2(Points,Centroids,'euclidean');
 [~, WhichCentroid] = min(Dist,[],2);
```

(in the while loop) with

```
    Dist = bsxfun(@minus,dot(Centroids',Centroids',1)' / 2 , Centroids * Points'  );
    [~, WhichCentroid] = min(Dist,[],1);
    WhichCentroid = WhichCentroid';
```

the code ran much faster, especially when K is large (K=32)

Thank you everyone!